# Effective way in LINQ of joining based on index

Tags: c#, linq

I have written code that works, but I can't seem to find a better way to combine the lists together if they have the same index.

```
    class Apple {};
    class Carrot {};

    var apples = new list<Apple>();
    var carrot = new list<Carrot>();

    var combine = from a in apples
                  from c in carrots
                  where apples.IndexOf(a) == carrots.IndexOf(c)
                  select new {a, c};
```

(When I say combine, I don't mean append to the end of the list. {{a,b},{a,b}, .... { }}: Maybe I have the terminology wrong when trying to research.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Zip`:

```
var combine = apples.Zip(carrots, (a, c) => new { Apple = a, Carrot = c});
```

Comment: where apples.IndexOf(a) == carrots.IndexOf(c) - condition is missing

Comment: No, op just wants to get a pair according to their index. Zip does it automatically

Answer (score 5):

```
apples.Select((a,i)=> new { Apple = a, Carrot = carrots[i] });
```

That should work too.

Comment: This will throw if apples array has more elements than carrots array.